# Google Music Manager launches every time I start Windows

Tags: windows-xp, google-music

I just installed Google Music Manager on Windows XP Pro.

Every time I turn on the PC, Music Manager is starting.

How can I uninstall Music Manager and stop this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of these two options to avoid running Musicmanager as you start the computer:

1. Check Windows Startup Folder and see if Musicmanager shotcut is there. The shortcuts in the startup folder will be executed as you login in Windows.
2. Check the system configuration:

   - Open a command prompt and type `msconfig`
   - Goto Windows Startup tab
   - Check if there's any item that references Musicmanager.
   - You can either untick the item or go to the items place in the registry and delete from there.

Answer (score 2):

You could actually just open up the program normally (double click on the orange headphones in the system tray, for example), and click on the Advanced Tab

[image]

From there Uncheck the box next to "Start Automatically when computer is restarted".  Then restart the computer, and Music Manager should not start automatically.

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Interestingly Google Music doesn't honour this setting on my system, it starts regardless.